# Cannot access assets in WebView on Android KitKat

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I've got a library included in my project, which exposes some assets in assets directory.
When running the app on Android 7, it works great and webview loads the assets fine. Today I have tested the app on Kitkat (API 19), and the resources loaded like `file://android_asset/someAsset.png` are not loaded.

I have checked the aar file created for my library and it contains those files [obviously, since the APK works fine on Android 7].

Here are my web settings:

```
    WebSettings s = getSettings();
    s.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    s.setSupportZoom(false);
    s.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    s.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    s.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    s.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    s.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    s.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        s.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    }
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        s.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        s.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

    }
    s.setGeolocationEnabled(false);
```

The error I get when debugging chrome is: `File not found`.

I have read some questions posted on SO, which refer to an IntelliJ setting: `"Include assets from dependencies into APK"` which is not there in Android Studio anymore. I have found however this doc page: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html which indicate, that adding

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':myLib')
}
```

is enough to provide the assets to the main project [and it clearly does, hence the AAR contents].

Still, I cannot get those resources to show up.

I have also tried to copy the assets directory from the library to the main project, but still no luck. They are not loaded by webview and I get the same error.

Comment: Try `file:///`, not `file://`. I have been loading content from assets into `WebView` without issue. See [Tutorial #12](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EmPubLite-AndroidStudio/T12-Book/EmPubLite) from [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android), for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question, because however stupid the problem is, who knows, maybe someone will stumble upon a similar issue.

I use `shouldInterceptRequest` method of `WebViewClient` to load files for `WebView`, as all of the content is encrypted and I have to decrypt it first.

Starting with Lollipop, the method has a different signature:

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
```

instead of

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(final WebView view, String url)
```

Since I have wrote my code using new devices, I simply had:

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) { ... }
```

and it worked fine. When testing on old device, the method was not triggered at all and it would not find the file where it expected it.

After I have added support for this method, it all started to work.

Thanks @CommonsWare for the comment.